# how to get null in the drop down value

Tags: java, save

I have 2 drop downs with unequal lengths. I am passing the values of each dropdown to the controller and from there after doing some operations I am saving the same to the database.

I have a query as If the first dropdown has 4 entries and second dropdown has 7 entries then the last 3 entries of first dropdown passed to the controller should be null. how can I achieve it.

I have tried with some code but its not working.

```
if(firstDropdownNames != null || secondDropdownNames != null){
  for(int i=0; i < Math.max(firstDropdownNames.length,secondDropdownNames.length); i++)
    {
        if(secondDropdownNames.length> firstDropdownNames.length){
           int j= secondDropdownNames.length - firstDropdownNames.length;
            if(i==j){
            String firstDropdownId = null;
            firstDropdownNames[i] = null;
            String secondDropdownId = service.getSecondId(secondDropdownNames[i]);
            Pair pair = new Pair(ProjectId, firstDropdownId, firstDropdownNames[i], secondDropdownId, secondDropdownNames[i]);
            service.save(pair);
           }
        }
       else if(firstDropdownNames.length> secondDropdownNames.length){
           int j= firstDropdownNames.length - secondDropdownNames.length;
            if(i==j){
            String secondDropdownId = null;
            secondDropdownNames[i] = null;
            String firstDropdownId = service.getFirstId(firstDropdownNames[i]);
            Pair pair = new Pair (ProjectId, firstDropdownId, firstDropdownNames[i], secondDropdownId, secondDropdownNames[i]);
            service.save(pair);
           }
        }
        else{
          String firstDropdownId = service.getFirstId(firstDropdownNames[i]);
           String secondDropdownId = service.getSecondId(secondDropdownNames[i]);
           Pair pair = new Pair (ProjectId, firstDropdownId, firstDropdownNames[i], secondDropdownId, secondDropdownNames[i]);
          service.save(pair);
    }
    response.setMessage("Saved successfully");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If

```
firstDropdownNames.length == 7 and secondDropdownNames == 4
```

then for

```
int j= firstDropdownNames.length - secondDropdownNames.length;
```

j will always be 3, therefore

```
i==j
```

will only be true when i == 3. What you probably want instead of i==j is:

```
if(i >= secondDropdownNames.length)
```

(assuming secondDropdownNames.length is shorter otherwise use firstDropdownNames.length)

Also, what are the types of firstDropdownNames and secondDropdownNames. It looks like they are arrays. If so, then you have to be careful because if secondDropdownNames.length == 4 and you try secondDropDownNames[i] = null when i>= 4, then you will get an illegal argument exception because you are trying to set a value outside of the array bounds.

Comment: yes this will be the case . so how can I resolve this problem of getting an illegal argument exception because I will set a value outside of the array bounds.

Comment: both of them are arrays and when I am saving I have to pass secondDropDownNames[i] = null when i>secondDropdownNames.length it will throw illegal argument exception.

Comment: You probably don't need the call "firstDropdownNames[i] = null;" or "secondDropdownNames[i] = null;"  instead, try creating your Pair like this: Pair pair = new Pair(ProjectId, null, null, secondDropdownId, secondDropdownNames[i]); or new Pair(ProjectId, firstDropDownId, firstDropdownNames[i], null,null);